# Styling the arrow on bootstrap tooltips

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm trying to style tootltips using

```
.tooltip-inner{}
```

But i'm having troubles cause i can't find how to style tooltip small arrow.

As shown on screenshot the arrow of the tooltip is black i want to add new color on that:

[image]
any suggestion?

Comment: You need to provide more detail, and possibly an example of your issue and an explanation of what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Morpheus i can't, tooltip fade out when mouse hover

Comment: Why was this marked duplicate when the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color) was actually asked _after_ this one?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use this to change tooltip-arrow color

```
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000000; /* black */
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for retrieving class, now .. how do you make it in diferent color? i tryed both background and color css rules but  it seems they don't works

Comment: you solely need to change `border-bottom-color` to a different color.

Comment: Every answer seems to be defining, or rather re-defining, properties that are not needed. All you need is: 

.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow{
    border-top-color: #b30838;
}
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow{
    border-lef-color: #b30838;
}
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow{
    border-bottom-color: #b30838;
}
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow{
    border-right-color: #b30838;
}
.tooltip-inner{
    background-color:#b30838;
}

Comment: The accepted answer does not work for me (at least with Bootstrap 3). Need to modify it slightly, i.e. remove the .bottom and just use .tooltip .tootip-arrow { etc }

Answer (score 34):

Use this style sheet to get you started !

```
.tooltip{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1020;
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:11px;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0)
}
.tooltip.in{
    opacity:.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80)
}
.tooltip.top{
    margin-top:-2px
}
.tooltip.right{
    margin-left:2px
}
.tooltip.bottom{
    margin-top:2px
}
.tooltip.left{
    margin-left:-2px
}
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow{
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-5px;
    border-left:5px solid transparent;
    border-right:5px solid transparent;
    border-top:5px solid #000
}
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow{
    top:50%;
    right:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-top:5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
    border-left:5px solid #000
}
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow{
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-5px;
    border-left:5px solid transparent;
    border-right:5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:5px solid #000
}
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow{
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-top:5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
    border-right:5px solid #000
}
.tooltip-inner{
    max-width:200px;
    padding:3px 8px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#000;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px
}
.tooltip-arrow{
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I have created fiddle for you.

Take a look at <kbd>[**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/w6dqz/2/)</kbd>

```
<p>
    <a class="tooltip" href="#">Tooltip
        <span>
            <img alt="CSS Tooltip callout"
                 src="http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/src/callout.gif" class="callout">
            <strong>Most Light-weight Tooltip</strong><br>
            This is the easy-to-use Tooltip driven purely by CSS.
        </span>
    </a>
</p>
```

```
a.tooltip {
    outline: none;
}

a.tooltip strong {
    line-height: 30px;
}

a.tooltip:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.tooltip span {
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 28px;
    width: 240px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

a.tooltip:hover span {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    color: #111;
    border: 1px solid #DCA;
    background: #fffAF0;
}

.callout {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    border: 0;
    left: -12px;
}
/*CSS3 extras*/
a.tooltip span {
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
}
```

Comment: +1 u rock! but can you tell me which classes are involved only for arrow styling? )

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick its image file you need to create it as per your design...

Comment: Fiddle displays poorly
http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-08-24_at_9.38.01_AM-tlLcxVxo.png

Comment: @shaheenery yeah right but if you see carefully someone has deleted image located at http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/src/callout.gif

Answer (score 11):

The arrow is a border.
You need to change for each arrow the color depending on the 'data-placement' of the tooltip.

```
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
  border-top-color: @color;
}
.tooltip.top-left .tooltip-arrow {
  border-top-color: @color;
}
.tooltip.top-right .tooltip-arrow {
  border-top-color: @color;
}
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
  border-right-color: @color;
}
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
  border-left-color: @color;
}
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: @color;
}
.tooltip.bottom-left .tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: @color;
}
.tooltip.bottom-right .tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: @color;
}
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: @color;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For styling each directional arrows(left, right,top and bottom), we have to select each arrow using **CSS attribute selector** and then style them individually.

**Trick:** Top arrow must have border color only on top side and transparent on other 3 sides. Other directional arrows also need to be styled this way.

[click here for Working Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/nvishnu/rc8kncjn/33/)

Here is the simple CSS,

```
.tooltip-inner { background-color:#8447cf;}

[data-placement="top"] + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-top-color: #8447cf;}

[data-placement="right"] + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-right-color: #8447cf;}

[data-placement="bottom"] + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow {border-bottom-color: #8447cf;}

[data-placement="left"] + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow {border-left-color: #8447cf; }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can always try putting this code in your main css without modifying the bootstrap file what is most recommended so you keep consistency if in a future you update the bootstrap file.

```
.tooltip-inner {
background-color: #FF0000;
}

.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
border-right: 5px solid #FF0000;

}
```

Notice that this example is for a right tooltip. The tooltip-inner property changes the tooltip BG color, the other one changes the arrow color.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me!

```
.tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
border-top: 5px solid red !important;}
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style only the colors of the tooltips do as follow:

```
.tooltip-inner { background-color: #000; color: #fff; }
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow { border-top-color: #000; }
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow { border-right-color: #000; }
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #000; }
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow { border-left-color: #000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are going around and around to figure this out and none of the options above are working, it is possible you are experiencing a **name space conflict** of .tooltip with bootstrap and jquery.

See this answer on how to fix: [jQueryUI Tooltips are competing with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731400/jqueryui-tooltips-are-competing-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score -2):

You can add 'display: none;' to .tooltip-arrow class

```
.tooltip-arrow {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: The current class to use for this is .tooltip .arrow