# How can we change the color of arrow in the popover of bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <div class="  affix  popover right" id ="one" style="margin-left:8em;margin-top:10em;  width:15em;background-color:rgba(228,19,47,0.9);padding:5px;border-radius:10px;">
    <div class="arrow" style="margin-top:-45px;"></div> 
    <center style="padding:20px;"><b>this is the message</b></center>
 </div>
```

This code creates the popover with a arrow how can we change the color of this arrow.

[image]

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38279489/3554107.
For styling each directional arrows, we have to select each arrow using CSS attribute selector and then style them individually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling the arrow on bootstrap tooltips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383440/styling-the-arrow-on-bootstrap-tooltips)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use this css changing border-right color of [**pseudo**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) element:

```
.popover.right .arrow:after {
  border-right-color: red;
}
```

#[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kree/)

Comment: This apparently changed to border-top-color, but it works well!

Answer (score 6):

In Bootstrap 4,

```
.bs-popover-top .arrow::after,
.bs-popover-auto[x-placement^="top"] .arrow::after {
    border-top-color: yellow; // Any color here
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine without the second identifier ".bs-popover-auto[x-placement^="top"] .arrow::after".  Is there something I'm not aware off that this should be required?

Answer (score 5):

Using a standard popover in Bootstrap 3, as in:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="this is the message">
  Popover on right
</button>
```

You can add the following **css** to your custom rules:

```
.popover {
  background-color: red; /*substitute 'red' with your color of choice*/
  border-color: red;
}
.popover.right>.arrow:after {
  border-right-color: red;
}
.popover-content {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found out that you need to override one class for each of the possible positions of the popover. In this example, my "tour" popover has a dark background and white text:

```
.popover[class*=tour-] {
    background: #434A54;
    color: white;
}

/* Needed to have the triangle match the grey background of the popover */
.popover[class*=tour-].top .arrow:after {
    border-top-color: #434A54;
}

.popover[class*=tour-].right .arrow:after {
    border-right-color: #434A54;
}

.popover[class*=tour-].bottom .arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: #434A54;
}

.popover[class*=tour-].right .arrow:after {
    border-left-color: #434A54;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap Popover with arrow and background color]

```css
.popover{
   background: #ebd997;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
}

.popover.top> .arrow:after {
    border-top-color: #ebd997;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With using bootstrap 4 popover template

```
template: "<div class=" popover yellow" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-body"></div></div>"



.yellow .arrow::after {
        border-top-color: black;
        border-bottom-color: black;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on this, but you can try changing

```
<div class="arrow" style="margin-top:-45px;"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="arrow" style="margin-top:-45px; color: red;"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 5:

```
.popover .popover-arrow:after {
  border-top-color: red;
}

.popover .popover-arrow:after {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.popover .popover-arrow:after {
  border-left-color: red;
}

.popover .popover-arrow:after {
  border-right-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The above didn't work for me for Bootstrap 5.1. Instead, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77405492 worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your using [Angular2/4/5](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host), with [NGX-Bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#container-body) I manage to change it with CSS, [click](https://plnkr.co/edit/UtOdt678DWsKHtyQViVb?p=preview) on normal text to popover on top. The others do not work because container="body" is not used. in [angular](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)  they create 
[_nghost-c0] if you use container="body".

```css
  :host /deep/.popover.top > .arrow:after 
{
     border-top-color: red;
}
:host/deep/.curvepopover{
    border-radius:10px;
    border:4px solid red;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bs-popover-top .arrow::after,
.bs-popover-auto[x-placement^="top"] .arrow::after {
    border-top-color: $blue; // Any color here
}

.bs-popover-bottom .arrow::after,
.bs-popover-auto[x-placement^="bottom"] .arrow::after {
    border-bottom-color: $blue; // Any color here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5:

```
.bs-popover-top .popover-arrow:after {
    border-top-color: red;
}

.bs-popover-bottom .popover-arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}

.bs-popover-start .popover-arrow:after {
    border-left-color: red;
}

.bs-popover-end .popover-arrow:after {
    border-right-color: red;
}
```