# How can I change the color of Bootstrap popover arrows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I've tried a few solutions found online when trying to change the color of my popover arrow. Here is my CSS which is in a self-created popover.css file (other css in here works fine).

```
popover.bottom .arrow::after {
    border-bottom-color: black !important;
}
```

Here is what styling is being applied in the DOM
[image: Here is what styling is being applied in the DOM]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what version of bootstrap you're using, but it looks like your selector isn't quite right. This works for me on version 4.0 (based on example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/):

```
.arrow::after, .bs-popover-bottom .arrow::after {
    border-bottom-color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**For Bootstrap 5, use this:**

```
.popover .popover-arrow::before, .popover .popover-arrow::after {
    border-color: #FFA500 !important;  /* this example changes the arrow to orange color... You can always replace with any color you choose. */
    border-top-color: transparent !important;
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
}
```

**Please note that at time off writing, bootstrap 5 is in alpha stage. This may or may not work with stable versions of bootstrap 5. I however doubt that anything much about the source code would change from this point onward.** • *So this should be pretty much standard for the stable release of Bootstrap 5.*

You can save the above code in a separate css file (say `custom.css`) and link it into your `HTML` file within the `<head></head>` section... Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: As of late 2021, Bootstrap `v5.1.1`, this works.  NB, depending on your environment, you may have to clear the browser cache for the changes to become visible.

Answer (score 0):

For **Bootstrap 5.1**, I had to use the following to get a `blue` background (change to your preferred color):

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .popover {
            background: blue;
        }

        .popover.bs-popover-top .popover-arrow:after {
            border-top-color: blue;
        }

        .popover.bs-popover-end .popover-arrow:after {
            border-right-color: blue;
        }

        .popover.bs-popover-bottom .popover-arrow:after {
            border-bottom-color: blue;
        }

        .popover.bs-popover-start .popover-arrow:after {
            border-left-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
```