# How to customize bootstrap popover design?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, customization

I want to use **[bootstrap popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/popovers/)** in my project that uses node-js also. The problem is that when I want to customize the design of that, I could not set any style to change the color or border of the small arrow that starts the popover.

You can see that with the help of custom class and [bootstrap template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/popovers/#options) that introduced in options part of documentation, I successfully changed the color and design of `.pop-class` custom class and `.popover-header` element. But I could not understand that which property-values of `.popover-arrow` I must change to have different color or border for my small arrows?

```js
/* define varible for getting button from html */
let myButton = document.getElementById("btnSearch");
/* define bootstrap popover */
var pop = new bootstrap.Popover(myButton, {
  trigger: "manual",
  title: "You must enter some text for searching in our site!",
  placement: "bottom",
  customClass: "pop-class"
});

/* if user clicks on button checks that the input search bar is "empty" or not, if it is empty "shows" the popover */
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let searchText = document.getElementById("search-bar").value;

  if (searchText.length < 1) {
    pop.show();
  }
});

/* if user clicks outside the search button this function hides the popover */
myButton.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  pop.hide();
});
```

```css
:root {
    --color1: rgb(65, 129, 171);
    --color2: rgb(124, 201, 222);
    --color3: rgb(229, 131, 185);
    --color4: white;
    --color5: rgb(236, 215, 110);
}

.pop-class {
  color: var(--color3);
  border-color: var(--color3);
}

.pop-class .popover-header {
  background-color: var(--color4);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-icons/1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" integrity="sha512-1fPmaHba3v4A7PaUsComSM4TBsrrRGs+/fv0vrzafQ+Rw+siILTiJa0NtFfvGeyY5E182SDTaF5PqP+XOHgJag==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<!-- bootstrap search bar -->
<div class="container-fluid" id="parentAll">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto">
      <div class="input-group my-5">
        <button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-outline-secondary px-5" type="button">
                    <i id="iconSearch" class="bi bi-search"></i>
                </button>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="search-bar">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Although bootstrap CDNs are added to the question, but the output in my local development environment is different from the output here. So I also put my output image below:

[image: output image in my local development environment]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the color of Bootstrap popover arrows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337652/unable-to-change-the-color-of-bootstrap-popover-arrow)

Comment: @isherwood thanks for your comment. It helped me a lot, But I also need to change the border-width and my popover is opening from bottom. So I posted my final result in the answer of this question.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you solved your problem. Don't forget to accept your answer to resolve this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment that @isherwood put in my answer, I finally found that these codes could change the border design of my popover:

```js
/* define varible for getting button from html */
let myButton = document.getElementById("btnSearch");
/* define bootstrap popover */
var pop = new bootstrap.Popover(myButton, {
    trigger: "manual",
    title: "You must enter some text for searching in our site!",
    placement: "bottom",
    customClass: "pop-class"
});

/* if user clicks on button checks that the input search bar is "empty" or not, if it is empty "shows" the popover */
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let searchText = document.getElementById("search-bar").value;

    if (searchText.length < 1) {
        pop.show();
    }
});

/* if user clicks outside the search button this function hides the popover */
myButton.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    pop.hide();
});
```

```css
:root {
    --color1: rgb(65, 129, 171);
    --color2: rgb(124, 201, 222);
    --color3: rgb(229, 131, 185);
    --color4: white;
    --color5: rgb(236, 215, 110);
}

/* ------------------------------- */
/* customizing the style of popover */
/* ------------------------------- */

.pop-class {
    color: var(--color3);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 3px solid var(--color3);
}

.pop-class .popover-header {
    background-color: var(--color4);
}

.pop-class .popover-header::before {
    border-bottom: transparent;
}

.pop-class .popover-arrow {
    top: calc(-.5rem - 2px);
}


.pop-class .popover-arrow::before {
    border-color: var(--color3);
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}


.pop-class .popover-arrow::after {
    border-top-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-icons/1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" integrity="sha512-1fPmaHba3v4A7PaUsComSM4TBsrrRGs+/fv0vrzafQ+Rw+siILTiJa0NtFfvGeyY5E182SDTaF5PqP+XOHgJag==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<!-- bootstrap search bar -->
<div class="container-fluid" id="parentAll">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto">
      <div class="input-group my-5">
        <button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-outline-secondary px-5" type="button">
                    <i id="iconSearch" class="bi bi-search"></i>
                </button>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="search-bar">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Although I added bootstrap CDNs to my answer, But the output in stack overflow is different from my local development environment. So I will add my final output image here:

[image: the output result image]