# Bootstrap tooltips arrow color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get red tooltips of [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) instead of the default black, by implementing inline style of the template option of the tooltip as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        options = {
          container: 'body',
          placement: 'right',
          template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow" style="color: red; border-color: red;"></div><div class="tooltip-inner" style="background-color: red;"></div></div>'
        };
        $('#lnk').tooltip(options);
      });
```

However, according to [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/tivixifiki/1/), the triangle shape of the arrow is distorted and becomes a square.

How could I, simply, solve this issue using the inline styling in the tooltip's template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling the arrow on bootstrap tooltips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383440/styling-the-arrow-on-bootstrap-tooltips)

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38279489/3554107.
For styling each directional arrows, we have to select each arrow using CSS attribute selector and then style them individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `border-color: red;` to `border-right-color: red;`

Comment: Thank you very much. I already, tried `border-bottom-color` However, it seems to depend on the placement property of the tooltip.