# How to change background color on tooltip?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

When I hover over on (i) tooltip background color is showing black how can I change background color to blue when user hover over on the tooltip.

so far tried code

glyphicon.html

```
<label for="epcfLevel3Name" class="col-md-5 required">EPCF:<span tooltip="{{epcfObj.epcfToolTip}}" id="tooltip" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign pull-right"></span></label>
```

css

```
#tooltip {
    position: relative;
    color: #66CCFF;
}
```

Comment: How is the background color set now? Show us **that** CSS.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color)

Comment: This is not directly related to the problem, but still important to note: Please be aware that `id` is a unique identifier, which means that you **must not** have two or more elements on a page with the same `id` value. So if you use the code you showed, there may be only **one** tooltip per html document.

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38279489/3554107.
For styling each directional arrows, we have to select each arrow using CSS attribute selector and then style them individually.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

**tooltip**

```
.tooltip-inner {
    color: #fff;
    background: #FF9900;
}
```

**tooltip arrow**

```
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow { border-top-color: #FF9900; }
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow { border-right-color: #FF9900; }
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #FF9900; }
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow { border-left-color: #FF9900; }
```

> Note: To override set !important

Comment: Use of `!important` should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: To override, do **not** use `important!`. Declare the same selector Bootstrap uses to style it, and make sure your definitions are loaded **after** Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked  for the background color but arrow is still showing black and another thing how can i adjust the height of the tooltip right now its going up and overlapping other html element.

Answer (score 0):

> template string
>
> ```
> <div class="tooltip" role="tooltip">
>     <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
>     <div class="tooltip-inner"></div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Base HTML to use when creating the tooltip.
>
> The tooltip's title will be injected into the `.tooltip-inner`.
>   `.tooltip-arrow` will become the tooltip's arrow.
>   The outermost wrapper element should have the `.tooltip` class.
>   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

#### To answer your question

> How can I change background color to blue when the user hovers over the tooltip?

Style the tooltip using the `.tooltip-inner` and `tooltop-arrow` selectors. The `.tooltip` selector should be left alone.

#### For example

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/sn1L2okg/1/))

```
.tooltip-inner {
    background: #66CCFF;
}
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top-color: #66CCFF; 
}
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow { 
    border-left-color: #66CCFF; 
}
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow { 
    border-right-color: #66CCFF; 
}
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow { 
    border-bottom-color: #66CCFF; 
}
```