# Change style of bootstrap tooltip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added comment button in my table.When I hover it tooltip will be displayed.
How to change style of tooltips? Can anyone help me?

```
.tooltip-arrow,
.cancelComments + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5h1ybdp1/3/

I tried using `popover` also but popover is not displaying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383440/styling-the-arrow-on-bootstrap-tooltips/38279489#38279489 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color

Answer (score 7):

Here are simple example

**HTML**

```
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
       title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom"
       class="red-tooltip">Tooltip on bottom</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;}
.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color:#f00; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/2htZe/

**Here is working fiddle with your code, the problem you didnt reference bootstrap.js!**

https://jsfiddle.net/5h1ybdp1/7/

Comment: Have you double checked if you referenced your bootstrap files in a proper way? Because I think this code should work. Also, maybe a link to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color) could clear out things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you supposed to write a script in order to generate a tool tip as follows and you haven't include `bootstrap.min.js`, `jquery`and `bootstrap.min.js` including order is also important. This will resolve your issue here is your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8q88jrtr/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("i").tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
a i{margin:50px 0 0 50px;}
#my-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color:#EF5438;}
#my-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow {border-top:5px solid #EF5438;}
</style>
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ur 
Facebook" id="my-tooltip"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

Comment: You should explain what this code does. And also apply the correct formatting please.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Markup adding title and content in bootstrap-3  tool-tip
```

//add this script in footer or header after bootstrap js, css and jquery resources

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //tooltip added on attribute "data-toggle"
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                $(".tooltipControl").popover({ trigger: "hover" });
</script>
```

Html

```
<a links tooltipControl" data-content="No Detail" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Title">See tooltip Here</a>
```