# Rails bootstrap tooltip style not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails 4.0 site using bootstrap 3.0. The tooltip is displaying but with no style. The bootstrap example shows that the markup will look like this

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

However when I inspect it, the markup generated looks like it is jQuery not bootstrap.

```
<div id="ui-tooltip-18 role="tooltip" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content">
</div>
```

Here is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Here is my JavaScript calling the tooltip

```
$(function(){
  $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
```

Here is my markup on the page:

```
<h3>Verifications</h3>
<table>
  <% @verification_types.each do |type| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to "#{type.name}", '#', data: { toggle: "tooltip" }, title: "Default title" %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have jQueryUI included? jQuery doesn't have tooltips.

Comment: Yeah I do, it is being included with this line `//= require jquery_ujs` in the application.js

Comment: There's probably a way to scope it, but you could probably also build a custom jQueryUI package without tooltip().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731400/jqueryui-tooltips-are-competing-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: I tried to use that earlier and it was still generating the same markup. Unless I am putting it in the wrong section.

Comment: I get an error when trying that solution `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.widget.bridge')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate this way around it but I got it to work. I had to add a js file I called it fix_tooltip.js and added this to it `$.fn.bstooltip = $.fn.tooltip;` then in my script that is calling `tooltip` it now does `$('[data-toggle]').bstooltip();` It feels really hacky and don't like it. But I couldn't get it to work by changing the jQuery-UI tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with the following working solution:

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require fix_conflict
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require others
//= require_tree .
```

fix_conflict.js (thanks for @covard)

```
$.fn.bstooltip = $.fn.tooltip;
```

others.js

```
$('.form a').bstooltip();
#IMPORTANT: Make sure to target the exact element on which the tooltip is defined
```

HTML

```
<form class='form' ...>
  ...
  <a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' title="some tooltip text>?</a>
  ...
 </form>
```

**IMPORTANT**: As mentioned above - targeting the ***exact element*** where the tooltip is defined is important. Otherwise when using a generic targeting `$('.form').bstooltip()` I ended up with the JQuery styling/tooltip

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure out a simple solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

@tamersalama 's answer helped me figure out a simple solution:

Do not include all jquery-ui plugins but rather just those you need (minus the tooltip plugin)

Here's my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```