# Meteor smart package jquery UI and bootstrap tooltips are interfering

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have both jquery UI and bootstrap installed as smart packages in my Meteor project.

Jquery UI and bootstraps tooltips interfere with each other. Searching google I found a fix:

[jQueryUI Tooltips are competing with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731400/jqueryui-tooltips-are-competing-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Which is to run some code after jquery UI has loaded and before bootstrap has loaded.

How can this be done with Meteor though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of this solution/hack is that you add dependencies to packages. So they will load in proper order:

```
jqueryui -> jQueryUIBootstrapFix -> myBootstrap
```

Here is instruction how you can do it:

Create local package **jQueryUIBootstrapFix** and **myBootstrap**.
You can do that using [em](https://github.com/EventedMind/em) and typing in console :

```
em g:package jQueryUIBootstrapFix
em g:package myBootstrap
```

Open `packages/jQueryUIBootstrapFix` and make sure  packages.js look like this:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'jQueryUIBootstrapFix',
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use('jqueryui', 'client');
  api.add_files('jQueryUIBootstrapFix.js', ['client']);
});
```

Then open `packages/myBootstrap` and copy all files from `packages/boostrap-3` (overwrite).
Remove `smart.json` from this dir.
Open `packages/myBootstrap/package.json` and change

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Provides bootstrap 3."
});
```

to

```
Package.describe({
  name:'jQueryUIBootstrapFix',
  summary: "Provides bootstrap 3."
});
```

In the same file add line:

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use('jquery');
  api.use('myBootstrap');
  ...
})
```

In the end add to end of the file `.meteor/release` your local packages:

```
jQueryUIBootstrapFix
myBootstrap
```