# List of conflicts between bootstrap and jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't find such list (bootstrap and jquery-ui conflicts) in the internet.

If you have used both together in one project may be you could aware me what kind of conflicts bother you?

What I have met:

1. tooltip function
2. h? styles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQueryUI Tooltips are competing with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731400/jqueryui-tooltips-are-competing-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly between `ui.button` and `ui.tooltip` plugins. This is easily remedied though with scripts included like so:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    // handle jQuery plugin naming conflict between jQuery UI and Bootstrap
    $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    $.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But I don't include any of the jQuery UI CSS, so I don't have anything to offer on CSS conflicts, if there are any.

<sup>*Added this as answer instead of a comment to include code snippet</sup>