# Bootstrap tooltip is appearing as the default tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I want my tooltip message is in black color box as showing the bootstrap documentation but I am getting the default  tooltip text. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
<html><head>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.13.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
<script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>

<script>

   $("#a").tooltip();

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<button id="a" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I really appreciate if someone tell me the real concept with the solution of my problem. What will I do? [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xvsqew6kCtzBzpDhhEST?p=preview)

Thank You.

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/19247955 as I see you are including both jQuery UI and Bootstrap, they both use tooltip, so there possible is a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you havent include **jquery** and the required **bootstrap javascript file**.

The placement of the stylesheets and javascript will be also important. Try to place the **bootstrap javascript file** and the **bootstrap stylesheet file** at the end of other stylesheets and javascripts files.

**Notice:** id is unique! It will be wise to use **class** or the **data-toggle** as selector.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>



<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<button id="a" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

Comment: thanks , sequence of the bootstrap js and css is the real issue using them at the end of other css and js file. now code is working  as i expected.

Comment: @mystertyboy Please note that this method is an override. But if it work for you case then I guess its ok :D You could also exclude tooltip from jquery ui with a custome build or even rename the jquery tooltip namespace.

Comment: rename jquery tooltip namespace  and excluding tooltip from jquery.  I didnot know  this solution. Thanks to guide these  thing. It's more interesting  way to solve this  overriding method issue.  Is their anyway  which guide me how many function of a js file is override by another js file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code I think this will help you..

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn right" title="" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('button').tooltip();
```

And External Resources are :

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
<script>

   $("#a").tooltip();

</script>
```

Replace your script with this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kao1s7og/)