# Adding tooltip to Bootstrap via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a standard tooltip to all elements in my DOM that have a certain class. Here's what I do:

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 add_standard_tooltips();
  });
  
  
function add_standard_tooltips(){
 $('.has_standard_tooltip').attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip');
 
 // Add tooltip text specific to classes 
 $('.zeon-edit-pencil').attr('title', 'My Tooltip text');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'zeon-edit-pencil has_standard_tooltip'>Edgar
</div>
```

The code works fine with the only exception that the tooltip does not appear in Bootstrap style (black background and white text), it looks like standard html tooltip. What am I doing wrong here ?!

UPDATE 1:
I guess, there's no Bootstrap in the Stackoverflow code snippet tool, so I provide [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4354jy5v/) just in case

UPDATE 2:
Here's the original code in my project:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: `jsfiddle.net/4354jy5v/1/`

**You forgot to init the tooltips**

`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

Just fyi: ensure that you always include bootstrap.js after jquery.js

Comment: pleinx, your jsFiddle seems to ok, so I ticked the question as sovled, but in my own project tooltip is again plain-vanilla instead of Boostrap-like

Comment: I've added my original code in the asnwer. After modifying js as per your suggestion, I still get the plain-vanilla appearance ((( The jquery-ui.js is included before boostrap.js

Comment: I cant find your original code, maybe forget to copy fiddle link? I see only "`UPDATE 2: Here's the original code in my project:`"

Comment: pleinx, I can fill that I have two problems. The first one you solved in your asnwer ($('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); was missing in my code). And the second one is not related to this question-thread, so let us close this discussion. If I do not succeed to solve it, will ask in a new question )

Comment: alright :) maybe take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731400/jqueryui-tooltips-are-competing-with-twitter-bootstrap i know its with jquery-ui but maybe the solutions also works with small modifications on vanilla-js

Comment: Update: In bootstrap 5, you should use this initialize: `$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`