# Jquery tooltip conflict with Bootstraps in context of using RequireJS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

This is a well-known problem with references [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731400/jqueryui-tooltips-are-competing-with-twitter-bootstrap/26476505)
Jquery and Bootstrap have naming conflict for `tooltip()`

The solution many have suggested is to use `$.widget.bridge` before Bootstrap is loaded. But in my case, I do not know how to achieve it using requireJS style:

My script import look like this:

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'knockout', 'bootsrap'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an old unanswered question. Since I stumbled over it when I had the same problem, here is how I solved it:

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui'],
      callback: function($) {
        $.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This forces requireJS to load jQuery UI and implement the bridge before bootstrap is loaded.

This might be considered a dirty workaround. However, since this code snippet configures how the different dependencies are loaded and solves a conflict between two dependencies, I think this is a good place for that line of code to live.