# Using Bootstrap & jQueryUI with TypeScript - Getting (TS) Duplicate property 'tooltip'

Tags: typescript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, definitelytyped

I have installed jQueryUI & Bootstrap in my .NET MVC project & loaded types for typescript with npm

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.x",
    "@types/jqueryui": "1.12.x",
    "@types/jquery.validation": "1.16.x",
    "@types/bootstrap": "5.1.x"
  }
```

I am getting following errors while code compilation since `'tooltip'` is available in both bootstrap & jQueryUI.

```
(TS) Duplicate property 'tooltip'
```

[image]

Any ideas how I can use Bootstrap & jQuery with types for typescript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQueryUI Tooltips are competing with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731400/jqueryui-tooltips-are-competing-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: No, this is for javascript, I am having issue while using Typescript with types

Comment: Can you show the lines of code that have the error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not with the `package.json` dependencies, it would rather be in your `tsconfig.json`.

I'd recommend removing `@types/bootstrap` and `@types/jqueryui` from `tsconfig.json`.

Instead use `import 'bootstrap';` or `import 'jquery-ui'` (not `jqueryui`) in the class where you need it's definitions.

The difference between `tsconfig` and `importing` manually is that tsconfig would make those types available globally when you might not necessarily need them all the time.

One note though, you may want to add the following to your tsconfig as well as for when you import `jqueryui`, you won't write `import 'jqueryui`, instead you will use `jquery-ui`:

```
"paths": {
      "jquery-ui": ["node_modules/@types/jqueryui"]
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when using types for bootstrap "5.1.x" but after I downgraded to v4 the problem seemed to be gone.

The following command:

```
> npm i "@types/bootstrap@^4"
```

added "^4.6.2" version to my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.16"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct answer as one solution to problem.

Comment: Downgrading Bootstrap is not a solution.